# can I use Linq to Xml to alter an XSD?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I've got a node in an XSD that I'd like to modify. I'd like to change the "name" value in this node:

`<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">`

However when I try to find that node via this code, I get either no nodes or an error, depending on what I try.

`xsdDoc.Descendants("element").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "NewDataSet").Single().SetAttributeValue("name",  "newValue");`

Linq To Xsd isn't an option, since it looks like it's open source and that will mean all sorts of red tape (at work).

Is this possible, or am I out of luck?

Related (but not the same): [Linq to XML - update/alter the nodes of an XML Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331502/linq-to-xml-update-alter-the-nodes-of-an-xml-document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an XNamespace for the "xs" namespace, then you need to use `xsdDoc.Descendants(ns+"element")`.

---

```
XNamespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
doc.Descendants(xs + "element").
    Where(x.Attribute("name") != null 
    &&  x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "NewDataSet").First().
    SetAttributeValue("name", "newValue");
```

Comment: Like so: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemaelement"? That doesn't seem right, but I see where you're going...

Comment: Ahh, like so: 
XNamespace xn = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
                IEnumerable<XElement> elems =  xsdDoc.Descendants(xn+"element").Where(
                     x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "NewDataSet");

Comment: This whole XDocument/X* namespace is just a little weird.

Comment: It sure looks right, but I'm getting a null ref exception on the lambda the second time I for-each it.

Comment: Same result if I do it with .Single().SetAttributeValue()

Comment: What fixed it? I found a second bug - need to check for x.Attribute("name") != null before accessing .Value.

Comment: I changed .Single() to .First() and that did it for some reason. Still wrapping my head around lambdas. Apparently. You're right about the null check, that's what was killing me.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but it could be a namespacing problem, try using LocalName, like in this question:

[Ignore namespaces in LINQ to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145659/ignore-namespaces-in-linq-to-xml)