# how to edit xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<Family_Inventory>
  <FamilyCategory>Curtain Panels
    <FamilyName>System Panel
        <FamilySymbol>Glazed</FamilySymbol>
        <FamilySymbol>Wall</FamilySymbol>
    </FamilyName>
  </FamilyCategory>

  <FamilyCategory>Curtain Panels
    <FamilyName>Rectangular Mullion
      <FamilySymbol>2.5" x 5" rectangular</FamilySymbol>
    </FamilyName>
  </FamilyCategory>
  ...........
  ...........// many other family categories
  ...........

</Family_Inventory>
```

i want create only one FamilyCategory tag based on its value as above is 'Curtain Panels'
so output will be

```
<Family_Inventory>
  <FamilyCategory>Curtain Panels
    <FamilyName>System Panel
        <FamilySymbol>Glazed</FamilySymbol>
        <FamilySymbol>Wall</FamilySymbol>
    </FamilyName>

    <FamilyName>Rectangular Mullion
      <FamilySymbol>2.5" x 5" rectangular</FamilySymbol>
    </FamilyName>

  </FamilyCategory>

  ...........
  ...........// many other family categories
  ...........

</Family_Inventory>
```

Please tell me how Can i do this?.

Thanks in Advance
Regards,
Nitin

Comment: This question might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331502/linq-to-xml-update-alter-the-nodes-of-an-xml-document

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation on [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) and it's associated classes.  There is also plenty of examples of how to use them online.

[Here](http://www.csharpkey.com/csharp/xml/Lesson01.htm) is an introduction to XML with C#.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to use linq to get the whole document... then just create two classes

```
class FamilyCategory
{
    string name;
    List<FamilyName> familyNames;
}

class FamilyName
{
    string name;
    List<string> familySymbol;
}
```

after you parse the whole document just sort them by familyCategory.. then you just go through the list. You create a new instance of FamilyCategory and add all the FamilyNames to its list... For each new Cateogry you create a new class... after that you just need to add them all back which is described [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but I think it's close.  It's a very manual approach, and there may be a slicker way to do it, but it's just manually grouping the categories into a new xdocument called groupedCategoryDocument.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var groupedCategoryDocument = XDocument.Parse("<Family_Inventory />");


foreach(var category in doc.Root.Elements("FamilyCategory"))
{
  //create the category for the new document
  var groupedCategory = new XElement("FamilyCategory", category.Text);

  //get all of the families for this category
  foreach(var familyName in category.Elements("FamilyName"))
  {
     //add to new document
     groupedCategory.Add(XElement.Parse(familyName.ToString());
  }

  // add category to new document
  groupedCategoryDocument.Add(groupedCategory);
}
```

On third preview, I think the XML you are trying to generate is too complex and I think this will be the easiest both in terms of generation & consumption

```
<Family_Inventory>
  <Family category="{category-name}" name="{family-name}" symbol="{symbol-1}"/>
  <Family category="{category-name}" name="{family-name}" symbol="{symbol-2}"/>
  ...
  <Family category="{category-name}" name="{family-name}" symbol="{symbol-n}"/>
</Family_Inventory>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use XSLT and grouping by keys. In this case it is complicated by the use of mixed content for "category" and "name"; it makes the key construction non-obvious:

`normalize-space(./node()[1])` The first child node of FamilyCategory is assumed to be a text node that contains the category name,; it is further trimmed w.r.t. white space.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="category" match="FamilyCategory" use="normalize-space(./node()[1])" />
<xsl:template match="Family_Inventory">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each
            select="FamilyCategory[count(. | key('category', normalize-space(./node()[1]))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(./node()[1])" />
                <xsl:for-each select="key('category', normalize-space(./node()[1]))/FamilyName">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A good explanation of how it works is found here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml