# Remove all text nodes from XML file

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I want to remove all text nodes (but not any other type of node) from an XML file. How can I do this?

*Example Input:*

```xml
<root>
<slideshow id="1">
<Image>hii</Image>
<ImageContent>this</ImageContent>
<Thumbnail>is</Thumbnail>
<ThumbnailContent>A</ThumbnailContent>
</slideshow>
<slideshow id="2">
<Image>hii</Image>
<ImageContent>this</ImageContent>
<Thumbnail>is</Thumbnail>
<ThumbnailContent>B</ThumbnailContent>
</slideshow>
</root>
```

*Expected Output:*

```xml
<root>
<slideshow id="1">
<Image></Image>
<ImageContent></ImageContent>
<Thumbnail></Thumbnail>
<ThumbnailContent></ThumbnailContent>
</slideshow>
<slideshow id="2">
<Image></Image>
<ImageContent></ImageContent>
<Thumbnail></Thumbnail>
<ThumbnailContent></ThumbnailContent>
</slideshow>
</root>
```

Comment: I've rephrased your question slightly. Please undo if the result doesn't match what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
doc.DescendantNodes()
   .Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text ||
               x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
   .Remove();
doc.Save("clean.xml");
```

EDIT: Note that the above was before I realized that [`XCData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcdata.aspx) derived from [`XText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xtext.aspx), leading to the simpler:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
doc.DescendantNodes()
   .OfType<XText>()
   .Remove();
doc.Save("clean.xml");
```

Comment: Shouldn't `doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>().Remove()` suffice?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Indeed - I hadn't noticed that XCData derived from XText. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

This question should help:  [Linq to XML - update/alter the nodes of an XML Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331502/linq-to-xml-update-alter-the-nodes-of-an-xml-document)

You can use Linq to open the document and alter the values or remove the nodes altogether.