# Reading from and conditionally writing to complex XML files with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I suspect the solution to my problem to be very easy with LINQ to XML, but I'm rather new to it and just seem to run into walls. (Also, I couldn't find a decent tutorial which covers similar cases to mine, so if you can point me to anything there, it's highly appreciated!)

What I need to do is this:

- I've got an XML file that I have to read from, which you can find below. There's usually just one branch in the file, which contains multiple orders. Every order has a unique code. Those orders contain multiple parameters, each of which also has a unique code.
- I am given an order code and a parameter code, and I now have to find the right order, and within that order the right parameter.
- For this one parameter, I need to update the "numericalValue" and "stringValue" fields. 
  *This is the hard part for me: because of the two conditions stated above, it looks like I have to have to introduce two intermediate variables along the way, each having one condition in its* `where` *clause, and the second one building on the first.*
- I then have to write the whole XML file back to disk, now containing my two little changes. *With my intermediate variables described above, putting the whole thing together again like this looks like a particular thorny path for me.*

So here's my XML file:

```
<xyz version="1.2.3" 
     xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/xyz"
     xmlns:abc="http://www.mycompany.com/xyz/abc">
  <header>
    <!-- some unimportant stuff -->
  </header>
  <body>
    <abc:abc version="1.3">
      <abc:branches>
        <abc:branch>
          <!-- some unimportant stuff -->
          <abc:orders>
            <abc:order>
check this-> <abc:orderCode>FOO</abc:orderCode>
              <abc:orderParameters>
                <abc:orderParameter>
  and this->   <abc:parameterCode>BAR</abc:parameterCode>
                  <abc:billedValue>
                    <abc:value>
       then change -> <abc:numericalValue>10</abc:numericalValue>
       these two   -> <abc:stringValue>ten</abc:stringValue>
                    </abc:value>
                  </abc:billedValue>
                </abc:orderParameter>
                <abc:orderParameter>
                  <!-- similar contents -->
                </abc:orderParameter>
                <!-- some more orderParameter instances -->
              </abc:orderParameters>
            </abc:order>
            <abc:order>
              <!-- similar contents as above -->
            </abc:order>
            <!-- some more order instances here -->
          </abc:orders>
        </abc:branch>
      </abc:branches>
    </abc:abc>
  </body>
</xyz>
```

As I said, I suspect the solution is quite easy, but I can't seem to figure it out right now (especially the part where I have to write the whole thing back).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is ensured the elements with that order code respectively parameter code you are looking for exist the following snippet should give you an idea:

```
    string orderCode = "FOO";
    string paramCode = "BAR";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

    XNamespace abc = "http://www.mycompany.com/xyz/abc";

    XElement value = 
        doc
        .Descendants(abc + "order")
        .First(o => o.Element(abc + "orderCode").Value == orderCode)
        .Descendants(abc + "orderParameter")
        .First(p => p.Element(abc + "parameterCode").Value == paramCode)
        .Element(abc + "billedValue")
        .Element(abc + "value");

    value.SetElementValue(abc + "numericalValue", 20);
    value.SetElementValue(abc + "stringValue", "twenty");

    doc.Save(Console.Out); // do doc.Save("file.xml") to overwrite
```

Answer (score 0):

Jan - you should check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331502/linq-to-xml-update-alter-the-nodes-of-an-xml-document/335418#335418). It covers querying and saving - both items you are interesting in for LINQ-to-XML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My main problem is the *conditional* part though - I need to get a handle on exactly these two instances that I want to change, and then write them back into the otherwise unchanged XML document that I received.